# How can I benchmark the XML parser of my choice?

Tags: php, xml, dom, benchmarking, xmlreader

I will handle a huge XML file and I will go with XMLReader. Below are three ways to go with, but I need to know which one is the fastest. How can I know this? The planet.xml file is located at http://trash.chregu.tv/planet-big.xml.bz2 in case hat you may need it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider the PHP profiling extension:

http://www.php.net/apd

You can examine the results with pprofp:

http://www.compago.it/php/phpckbk-CHP-21-SECT-3.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with XML much in PHP, but if you're dealing with a really large file, a streaming parser is the way to go.  Reading the whole thing into memory and building a DOM tree is pretty expensive (and may even fail, if the document's too big to hold in memory).